# Can I set a dynamic range in vba excel to use in filter

Tags: excel, vba, range

The following excel sub is a filter that is filtering out rows based on the rows in the criteria row.
The code works well when the ranges are set with absolute data. I want to change the code to take the range from references stored as cell values (an indirect reference) but I cannot find a way to adapt other code snippets I see to work and I wonder if anyone can help me.  I am not a programmer.

The problem is that as new data is inserted from time to time the range reference will move and the start of the data an the associated filter is in cell (using RC notation 14,14) and the data in cell 13,12. While I know I can’t use the indirect function in vba I wondered if there is a way to dynamically assign a range to be able to use the Advance filter function. 
I have the code to find the last column and row of the data block.
I have tried the following code (2 attempts) but it won’t let me use the object in this way
I have tried to crate the cell reference as a string then assign it using the range function. I then read an answer where someone had put the value of the cells directly into the range function and it has worked for them ( they were copying cells). The 2 attempt are broadly the same but in the second I am trying to be more specific. 
The issue seems to be as soon as I change from an absolute reference "A50" in the range statement the range no longer works. I am unsure how to resolve this and perhaps it can't be

It may be helpful to know the that data being filtered is rows of name and telephone data along with a tally system to show attendance (one column per week for a year)
The cells with the dynamic data hold them in the form A1 not RC format

```
Sub UseAdvancedFilterInPlace()
'This version of the sub has absolute references and works perfectly
Dim rdData As Range
Dim rgcriteria As Range
Call TurnOffStuff
Set rgData = Sheet9.Range(“A50”).CurrentRegion
Set rgcriteria = Sheet9.Range(“A46”).CurrentRegion
rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rgcriteria
Call TurnOnStuff
End Sub

Sub UseAdvancedFilterInPlace()
'This version of the sub has dynamic references and fails
Dim rdData As Range
Dim rgcriteria As Range
Call TurnOffStuff
Dim Top_of_data As String
Dim Top_of_Criteria As String
Dim My_range As Range
‘Attempt 1
'Set rgData = Range(Sheet9.Cells(13, 12).Value).CurrentRegion
'Set rgcriteria = Range(Sheet9.Cells(14, 14).Value).CurrentRegion
'Attempt 2
Set rgData = Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Range(Cells(13, 12)).Value).CurrentRegion
Set rgcriteria = Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Range(Cells(14, 14)).Value).CurrentRegion

rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rgcriteria
Call TurnOnStuff

End Sub
```

The actual error message I get is an application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: The sub routines TurnOffstuff and TurnOnStuff, simple disable and enable screen updating and set calculations to manual to speed up the processing.

Comment: Which exact cells are you trying to set to rgData, and which to rgcriteria?

Comment: Also notice that you declare rdData but you use rgData.

Comment: I have retested correcting the variable name to a consistant rdData throughout.

Comment: The rdData is the data to be filtered (i.e the telephone numbers and the tallying, the rgCriteria is the criteria that the filter is to use. So for example I would set John in the name column of rgCriteria  and it would filter the data in rgdata to give only rows with john as a name. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: on re-reading your question I realise you may be asking something different the rdData range value (A51) is in cell L13 the value for rgCriteria range (A46) is in cell N15 hence cell(13,12) and cell (14,14) respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
Set rdData = Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Range("L13").Value).CurrentRegion
Set rgcriteria = Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Range("N15").Value).CurrentRegion
```

given that `Range("L13").Value` is A50 and `Range("N15").Value` is A46.

extra: Use the statement `Option Explicit` in the first line of every module, out of every sub or function. This option throws an error on undeclared variables, and will help you avoid renameing mistakes on variables.

Comment: Thanks have tried this and it works well. I notice that I made a mistake with cell referencing as well it should be A51 and that gives a different RC using your code makes it more readable. Thanks for your help. I've marked it as the solution.